# How to remove link in Hero webpart

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience, image-display, links

I added Hero web part in modern SharePoint online page and added some pictures in tiles.

Issue is that the pictures has to have a link.

But, I don't want to have links and just want to display the pictures. I tried using "#" but the system is not accepting.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're almost there actually with #. Just don't put plain #.
Edit your specific Hero image, select "From a Link", copy the address bar your current page URL removing all additional query strings, and then add #.
[image]

Comment: That worked.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to display pictures, just try to use the image gallery web part.

Have a try with it:https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-image-gallery-web-part-bbcbe560-14a7-4369-8ef5-3255845e3bfd

Answer (score 0):

If you are using you have to add a link to a document or page or Image. there is no out of the box to remove it.

Instead of using Hero webpart, you can use **Image Gallery** webpart in SharePoint Online. But you will not get the exact look and feel as of Hero webpart.

In Image gallery webpart, you will get 3 different layouts:

- Brick
- Grid
- Carousel

Also, you can choose to show the static/selected images or you can dynamically display images from a document library.

[image]

**Microsoft official documentation**: [Use the Image Gallery web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-image-gallery-web-part-bbcbe560-14a7-4369-8ef5-3255845e3bfd)

If you want the exact look and feel then you have to develop the custom webpart using [SharePoint Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview).

Comment: In worst case you have to provide the link to same page. It will not redirect user to another pages/link but it will refresh the same page.

Comment: Hi @Rajana, Does this answer your question? If Yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it will help others with same problem in future. If you have any doubt please ask here.

Answer (score 0):

a bit more detail:

To disable the link at the Hero frame level:

1. Edit the Hero webpart
2. Hover over the Hero frame you want to edit and click the pencil to edit
3. Click the Change button and paste in the URL of your site, replacing the "?" and everything to the right of it with a "#"

To disable the link at the Hero frame's "Call to action" level:

1. Within the "Call to action link" box, paste in the URL of your site, replacing the "?" and everything to the right of it with a "#"

Repeat for every Hero frame you want to remove the links from.

That's it!