# How can I remove link from a Sharepoint web tile?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience, sitepages, hero-web-part

I'm trying to remove link from a Hero Tile, so as it works as an image. I tried adding **#** in the end of the home page link, but this only refreshes the home page, which is quite annoying for the users.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to remove the links from hero web part tiles in SharePoint online modern experience.

Also, you cannot customize these SharePoint out of the box web parts.

You can Show/hide **call to action link** from web part properties but you cannot remove link from hero web part tiles as those has to have a link by default.

Either you have to add link to same page (as you did) or you have to use another web parts like image gallery web part or any other custom web part developed using SPFx.

Here's one example of custom SPFx web part: [React Hero web part](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-hero-webpart)

**Similar thread**: [How to remove link in Hero webpart](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/286726/how-to-remove-link-in-hero-webpart)

---

You can also add new feedback/idea on [SharePoint feedback portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/06735c62-321c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472) for Microsoft to allow removing links from Hero web part tiles.